# How to save the output of invoice2data to a file from bash?

Tags: python, bash

I want to save the output of invoice2data to a file.
Following is what I have tried
Command:

```
invoice2data aar.pdf --template-folder templates  > parsing_log.txt
```

The command prints following on screen

```
INFO:invoice2data.main:{'lines': [{'item_id': u'XX Labor', 'ea_price': u'100.00', 'total': u'100.00', 'description': u'10/10/2018 Todd Encardes', 'qty': u'1.00'}, {'item_id': u'Mileage', 'ea_price': u'1.00', 'total': u'20.00', 'description': u'Mileage', 'qty': u'20.00'}], 'currency': '$', 'amount': 120.0, 'date': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 16, 0, 0), 'invoice_number': u'1111', 'desc': 'Invoice from XXX Service', 'issuer': 'AAR Service'}
```

But parsing_log.txt is empty.
invoice2data is used to Extract structured data from PDF invoices, refer https://github.com/invoice-x/invoice2data 
invoice2data  is developed in python.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`invoice2data aar.pdf --template-folder templates  &> parsing_log.txt`

I suspect that line is sent to stderr, not stdout.